# PDF Press and CSS

Tags: add-on, pdf-press

Based on the PFD Press documentation:

> 1. Formatting the PDF File
>
> Formatting the PDF file is as simple as creating a special CSS file
>   and referencing it in the  tag in your template. Use the media
>   attribute and set it to "pdf". This will cause the PDF Press to use
>   the stylesheet (and it will be ingnored in your browser)
>
> `<link href="{site_url}css/pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" media="pdf">`

I have created mine CSS styes sheet and added to the header

```
<link href="{stylesheet='styles/pdf'}" rel="stylesheet" media="pdf">
```

Style sheet is loaded by the site but not added to generated PDF.

Any clue what can be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the add-on developer response:

> I think you might have to switch to a static CSS file or inline css in
>   order for the stylesheet to be parsed by PDF Press.

Inline CSS works fine.